# Using Camera Module V3 NoIR as Night-vision Camera

Tags: camera, picamera, libcamera

I have recently purchased a Rasberry Pi Camera module V3 NoIR wide lens to monitor the night-time activity of my pet. I have tried to capture video using libcamera and Picamera2 in dark(near-pitch dark) conditions but all I get is pitch-black footage. How should I tweak the camera controls like noise reduction/white balance to get infrared video?

Comment: Use infrared LEDs to illuminate the scene.

Comment: "Night vision" is a technical term that means a camera has a photomultiplier ahead of the lens and can function in exceedingly low light levels. The NOIR cameras is not a "night vision" camera. It is a camera with no IR filtering ahead of the lens, so it's more sensitive to IR light. It does NOT multiply the light that it receives.